# I want to make a Javascript browser scripts in console. What syntax is there to click/enter text/find values?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, scripting

Im a beginner in JavaScript and I want to make scripts in the console of the browser to do tasks. I cant find the syntax to do this. The only command I know of is document.getElementById() however Im struggling to find commands to click or enter text into a search box or something to input text in. 
Does anyone know how to do this?

Example of what I want to achieve:

Type Hello into the google search bar and press enter.

Also why has this question been put on hold it got answered...

Comment: Yes. I usually just use google. I type in stuff until I get what I need. I try to describe what I want to do in the search box and that usually gives me relevant results.

Comment: I try to find what I looking for in google but im having no luck...

Comment: @Vld +1, Google saves our lives)) The link I gave is the first in search results for "javascript"...but its OK, no problem to give a link if someone asks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use ruby with Capybara and Cucumber to do that https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara and if you still want to use javascript you can inspect the input and get the id and then do this:

```
document.getElementById('lst-ib').value = "Hello";
```

and for the click you could try this:

```
document.getElementsByName('btnK')[0].click();
```

but it didn't work for me.

And if you want to learn javascript you can do it in codeschool or codecademy for example.

Comment: YES thankyou. I changed the code and tried it on youtube and it worked. It doesnt seem to work on google.

Answer (score 0):

The best start will be: http://www.w3schools.com/js/
It has a lot of examples and will help you to make the first steps;)

Comment: The best start is ***never*** w3schools, in fact, it's not the best anything.

Comment: Where could I find the syntax that Im looking for?

Comment: @adeneo suggest something else to a person who knows only "document.getElementById() "...this one is also fun: https://www.javascript.com/try